# Global 'cache' variables in a requireJS AMD application

Tags: javascript, global-variables, requirejs

My application has a View() model that fetches HTML, CSS, etc. with a simple call to a view path. As many of these views and viewlets are shared or required multiple times I'd like to maintain a 'cache' object of loaded views that any new instance of a View() can check and read from if that particular view has been loaded.

In a requireJS implementation, any ideas on where is best to put this view 'cache' object? Ideally I'd like to have something like a Session() object that contains it, and I'd be able to reference a single instance of Session() from anywhere in my app.

Any thoughts on best practices for this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Singleton approach creating a simple module for this case. For instance, you could create a module like this:

```
define(["mydep","myotherdep"], function(dep1,dep2){
  var Hellovariable = {
       "attr1": ...,
       "attr2": ...,
  ...
       "attrN": ...
  }
  return Hellovariable;
});
```

When you call this module using AMD you will only have an unique instance for this variable and its attributes.